# How to transform following table to desired table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

| ID | StartDate (YY-MM-DD) | EndDate (YY-MM-DD) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20-07-13 | 21-05-12 |
| 2 | 15-04-12 | 27-01-01 |
| 3 | 14-01-30 | 18-12-30 |
| 4 | 18-02-21 |  |
| 5 | 20-12-12 | 20-12-15 |
| 6 | 20-11-11 |  |
| 7 | 19-10-22 | 20-08-10 |
| 8 | 17-09-01 | 19-04-15 |
| 9 | 18-06-27 | 21-08-19 |
| 9 | 19-08-17 |  |

I would like to write a query that creates an output with the following structure:
Count the IDs which are active during each period. For example ID: 1 was active between 13. July 2020 and 12. May 2021, so it should be added to the count during 202007 and 202105.
As long as there is now EndDate, the ID should be added to the count till the present period.

| COUNT_ID | YYYYMM |
| --- | --- |
| 150 | 201601 |
| 200 | 201602 |
| 180 | 201603 |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |

I struggle to find a way to calculate the count of active IDs for each period, I believe there is an simple way to do that but unfortunately I don´t know.

Any help/tip/hint is much appreciated!

Best regards,
Frederik

Comment: You need a calendar table, or even just a tally/numbers table as the base for your query. Then join to your details and count, grouping by month.

Comment: Does your first row indicate that there are 150 distinct ID's to be found in January of 2016?  Or does it indicate that there are 150 ID/day combinations?

Comment: I truly hope your "dates" are not actually those crazy strings and it is only what you posted. Otherwise the first step is in fixing your datatypes. For the question at hand your desired output doesn't seem to be consistent with your sample data. Help us understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SeanLange Hi, no the mentioned date-column was just me typing it in, the actual column in my table is a proper date column.

Comment: @pwilcox Sorry for not being specific, Yes, it indicates that there are 150 distinct ids for January 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you will want to:

Generate a table of month-start-and-end ranges, between a start date (June 2016) and present

Then, for each month, examine how many of your records' start and end dates contain any days that fall within that month

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_ids (id       INT,
                        id_start DATE,
                        id_end   DATE);

INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (1,'20200713','20210512');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (2,'20150412','20270101');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (3,'20140130','20181230');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start)         Values (4,'20180221');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (5,'20201212','20201215');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start)         Values (6,'20201111');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (7,'20191022','20200810');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (8,'20170901','20190415');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start, id_end) Values (9,'20180627','20210809');
INSERT INTO #temp_ids (id, id_start)         Values (10,'20190817');

DECLARE @windowStart DATE = '20160101',
        @windowEnd   DATE = GETDATE();

;WITH report_dates AS (--This is a convenient piece of code to generate a table of dates between two dates
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, 
                             @windowStart, 
                             @windowEnd) + 1
               )  
               DATEADD(DAY, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1,
                       @windowStart
               ) AS report_date
          FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b  
),
month_windows AS (--Filter the dates we just generated to only month-start, and add month-end
    SELECT report_date          AS month_start, 
           EOMONTH(report_date) AS month_end
      FROM report_dates
     WHERE DATEPART(DAY, report_date) = 1
)

    SELECT --Count the number of records which overlap with the month range
  DISTINCT month_start,
           month_end,
           COUNT(id) AS count_id
      FROM #temp_ids AS ti
      JOIN month_windows mw ON ((ti.id_start <= mw.month_start AND ti.id_end >= mw.month_start)
                              OR (ti.id_start >= mw.month_start AND ti.id_start <= mw.month_end)
                            )
     WHERE id_end IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY month_start,
           month_end
```